# Each non-empty interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(I)=f(\mathbb{R})$ when $f$ is additive

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an additive function such that $f(1)=0$. Then for each non-empty interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(I)=f(\mathbb{R})$.

Since $f$ is additive and $f(1)=0$ so $f(x+1)=f(x)$. How do we prove $f(I)=f( \mathbb{R})$ ??

Comment: What have you tried?  To start, suppose M is in the image of f, so f(Y) = M for some real Y.  Can you find a real number Y* between 0 and 1 for which f(Y*) = M ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hints**:

- It can be shown that $f(q)=0$ for each $q\in\mathbb Q$.
- It can be shown that for every $r\in\mathbb R$ there is a $q\in\mathbb Q$ with $r+q\in I$.